# Programmatically initialize navigation controller stack

Tags: ios, ios5

This is the code for the button press:

```
- (IBAction)newPoint:(id)sender {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navid"];
    UIViewController *tblvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tblid"];

    UINavigationController *nvc1 = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
    [nvc1 pushViewController:tblvc animated:NO];
    [nvc1 pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

This is my storyboard
[image]

This is exception I got:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show the rightmost view controller(in storyboard) when tapping on button. Then I want the back button of navigation controller to take to root view controller, just as I would reach that controller manually.

For that I change to the second tab(because button is on first tab), then I try to initialize Navigation controller. But there is something I probably missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have your storyboard IDs set on the correct view controllers within storyboards. To me it looks like either

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navid"];
```

Or

```
UIViewController *tblvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tblid"];
```

Is creating a new instance of a UINavigation controller. You could confirm this by using the following

```
    - (IBAction)newPoint:(id)sender {
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

        UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navid"];
        UIViewController *tblvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tblid"];

        NSLog(@"vc - %@",NSStringFromClass([vc class]));
        NSLog(@"tblvc - %@",NSStringFromClass([tblvc class]));

        UINavigationController *nvc1 = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
        [nvc1 pushViewController:tblvc animated:NO];
        [nvc1 pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
    }
```

Then check the class names in the debugger. whichever one is UINavigationController (or a subclass) is the one thats the problem.

Comment: You were right, the ID was incorrect. But is it right approach overall or there is a better one? Thank you

Comment: Yeah I'd say your approach is totally fine.